# How can I enforce a vector to be immutable?

Tags: c++, vector, immutability, mutable

I want to restrict vector to be unchanged. In following code when i use reference for each loop and increment each value, same is reflected in the vector. But I want to avoid.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> port = {8, 0, 8, 0};    
    for (auto &digit: port){
        digit++;
        std::cout << digit << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could just output `digit+1`

Answer (score 5):

use `const` keyword before `vector<int>`.

```cpp
const vector< int> port = {8,0,8,0};
```

Comment: Or use `const` keyword after `vector<int>`.  `vector<int> const port = {8,0,8,0};`

Comment: absolutely fine.